# How to programmatically change the orientation of the menu (when android:configChanges and android:screenOrientation is set)?

Tags: android, menu, orientation

given that:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

How do we manually change the menu (`android.view.Menu`) orientation as if the screen orientation is not fixed to `landscape`. I would like to know what API can be called to **change the menu orientation manually**. 
I have seen this app, "`com.sec.android.app.camera`", a stock camera app in Samsung galaxy (*gingerbread*), doing it. I have checked it `AndroidManifest.xml`, it has the above settings. Yet its menu does change according when the device is placed as `portrait`. Too bad I don't have the source code to it.
I'm done searching the whole day. Sigh.

Thanks.